# List user defined variables from a parent module (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-import

I have a function within a module that lists defined variables

Simplified Example:

```
    for var_name in globals():
        if not var_name.startswith('__'):
            var_value = eval(var_name)
            var_type = type(var_value)
            print(var_name, "is", var_type, "and is equal to ", var_value)
```

This works when I run it from within the origin module, but not when the module is imported to another script. It only ever reads the variables defined in the origin module.

I also tried:

```
import __main__
for var_name in __main__.__dict__:
```

But that didn't work either. How can I get this function to work when imported into another script?

Thanks!

Comment: Right.  `globals`, despite its name, is only global to a single file. Python does not have the concept of globals spanning multiple files or modules, and that's a Good Thing.   `__main__.__dict__` should do what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did use `__main__.__dict__`, I just wrote it wrong in my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean to use `__main__.__dict__`, not `__main__.dict`. That, with some minor loop modifications (i.e. `eval` will not work as you want it to in this context, instead use `__main__.__dict__[var_name]`) should get your code working.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did use `__main__.__dict__`, I just wrote it wrong in my question!
But you're right - using `__main__.__dict__[var_name]` solved it for me; thank you so much!